# will and would for expressing the present situation and certainty of the present

Tags: meaning

> She would/will know the secret between us.

What is the sentence below that has the most similar meaning to the meaning of this sentence above?

1. Maybe she knows the secret between us
2. Maybe She is going to know the secret between us.
3. Either 1 or 2 according to context.

I've looked up **"would and will"** in dictionaries and checked they can be used for describing the present situation and certainty of the present and read some answers on this site, but I'm still not sure what the sentence means.
I think it could mean 1 or 2 according to context.

Comment: The sentence you've given uses *would / will*. Those are different words. If you're asking for the specific meaning of the literal use of *would / will* (Or is it *would **and** will*, which is something else?), you're not going to get an answer that's anything other than highly subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"She would know the secret between us."
She already, most likely, knows the secret between us.

"She will know the secret between us."
She is going to, eventually, figure out our secret.